# Synchronize folders without WebDAV

Tags: windows-10, sync, nas, webdav

I'm looking to synchronize a network folder to a folder on a PC.

The target PC has a 50 MB WebDAV size limitation in place, therefore blocking the copying of larger files.
Using a browser (e.g. Chrome) to open the network folder, larger files can be downloaded just fine.

I've tried using [FreeFileSync](https://freefilesync.org/) and [Dsynchronize](http://dimio.altervista.org/eng/#DSynchronize), but both seem to use WebDAV to copy the files and are thus affected by the size limitation.

Is there a program I can use to syncronize the folders, bypassing the local file size limit / WebDAV?

Comment: Does the server only offers the WebDAV protocol?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _"Using a browser (e.g. Chrome) to open the network folder"_? Which protocol is this using?

Comment: @gronostaj I'm not sure. It's the same interface you get when opening a local folder adress (e.g. C:\Users\gronostaj\Desktop) in the Chrome address bar.

Comment: Can you share what's in the address bar? You can redact sensitive parts like IPs, domain names, exact path etc. but share the general structure

Comment: `file://servername/folder1/folder2/`

Comment: That could be SMB, I guess? Try entering `servername/folder1/folder2` into Windows Explorer's address bar.

Comment: @gronostaj That works, but copying files from there has the 50 MB restriction.